# PHP file not gettinig executed as expected

Tags: php, apache, web-services, server

I created a php file as shown below.

```
    <?php
    $ar = 4600;
    $az = "redshift -O ".$ar;
    echo "Command executed: ";
    echo $az;
    system($az,$status); // It is not working on browser but working on terminal.
    system("ls",$asd); // It is working on both browser and terminal.
    if($status == NULL) {
        echo "<h3>Operation not successful</h3>";
    }
    else 
        echo "<h3>Temperature Succesfully set to ".$ar."</h3>";
    ?>
```

Now, the matter is that
when i am running this file on terminal using command

```
php file.php
```

the 'ls' command is getting executed and 'redshift -O 4600' also getting   executed.
But when i am executing this file on browser using url.

```
127.0.0.1/file.php
```

Only 'ls' command is getting executed. 'redshift -O 4600' is not getting executed. Is there some way through which i can execute such programs.
I have also tried other functions like exec etc.

Comment: full path to `redshift` ? permission issue?

Comment: i changed the path to /usr/bin/redshift but it is still not getting executed

Comment: is the user running the script from the terminal the same as the user that runs apache?

Comment: @xatzistnr is probably correct. What is the output of `var_dump($status)`, that should contain a return code which will shed light on the issue?

Comment: the output of var_dump($status) is (int)1.

Comment: And I am also getting 'Temperature succesfully set to 4600.' in output. but I am not able to see the after effect of the execution of program

Answer (score 2):

It would not work as you are setting up your server at /var/www/html location which is used by public to access your computer through localhost. And since in localhost there is no such thing as redshift so it would run nothing and the operation would be executed and you will see no after effects. So, to run the system's command on localhost, you must run the server on any folder other than /var/www/html. So, to run the server on any other location, just go to that location and run
`php -S localhost:8080`.

Comment: Yeah , it worked thanks a lot. Then does it mean I can run multiple instances of server.Because, now I   am able to execute php scripts from both location s

Comment: Yeah you can @GauravKandoria